# php session.save_path failover

Tags: php, session

We have an array of autoscaling web servers on the cloud sharing sessions via a shared Network Attached storage.

We are considering other solutions but in the meantime I am looking for ways to make our system fault tolerant.

E.g. if shared storage is not available for whatever reason I would like php to ignore my session.save_path setting and fallback to the local filesystem instead.

Is there any clever workaround that would make this possible via standard php configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `auto_prepend_file` and do the check there and set the path to local if the path in the cloud is not available. This is not a fully automatic, ini only solution, but close to it.

Recommendation: if you want to share the session across several machines better use a database stored session solution.

Comment: Simple and should work well. We ll try it. Yes we are thinking of using amazon's nosql solution DynamoDB for sessions in the long run. As a temporary solution we ll go with your proposed approach. thanks!